# Air mobile CameraRoll not support on Jelly Bean devices

Tags: android, mobile, air

Surprised, but it true. CameraRoll in Air SDK 3.5 does not work with the new devices. For example, Samsung Galaxy SIII (GT-i9300) with Android Jelly Bean 4.1.1

Can someone faced with the decision?

```
private var c:CameraRoll;
if(CameraRoll.supportsAddBitmapData){    
    c = new CameraRoll();
    c.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSave);
    c.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onError);
    c.addBitmapData(bitmapData);
} else {
    ta.text += 'camera roll not support   \n';// not support for Samsung Galaxy SIII (GT-i9300) Android Jelly Bean 4.1.1
}
```

Comment: Does it work on another devices? Have you set all permissions? Maybe this one is required: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
Does it work with AIR 3.6 beta?

Comment: Yes, it work fine on another iOS and Android devices. No permissions required. I don`t try AIR 3.6 yet. Do you think this will help? My FB 4.7 uses SDK 3.5 and I not understanding how to use both SDK together.

Comment: If you don't want to try AIR 3.6 beta, you could check if you have the latest AIR 3.5 release. As of today it is 3.5.0.880 for Windows and 3.5.0.890 for Mac. If not, update should be easy – just backup the SDK folder and replace it with the new version. If that doesn't solve the problem, file a bug and hope it gets fixed fast. ;-) Sorry, I can't really help, but that's what I usually do.

Answer (score 0):

In android 4.1 and more you need set WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission